# What is the recommended way to store multiple OrderBy values in a database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a list of items with a sub-list of items with a sub-list of items (3 levels total).

The main level is sortable using jQueryUI (beyond the scope of this question so this functionality is not being shown). The main level is not sortable but LEVEL x.x can be moved up and down along the `axis-y` and then a separate sorting can be done on the level x.x.x. The `axis-y` is in place to prevent the LEVEL 1 from being able to be dropped on LEVEL 2.1.3 (if this happens, we'll be like Chuck Norris and will be able to divide by zero but I digress).

My question is what is best practice, to have each level with their own `sort by` column in the database or use a single column for anything that needs to be sorted?

Maria 10.x is in play.

**UPDATE**
For context, this will be a list of activities. You click on the arrow and the list will reveal the menu so the primary key will be activity id.

**UPDATE**
I'm providing the query I'm working with since I first started. I haven't received any direction yet but so hopefully this query might help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a c.coreID,
  c.coreLabel,
  a.phaseOrderBy,
  a.weekOrderby,
  a.dayOrderBy,
  c.groupID,
  a.woAID,
  a.phaseID,
  (CASE
    WHEN p.phaseID is null
    THEN CONCAT('NONE')
    ELSE p.phaseLabel
    END) as phaseLabel,
  a.weekID,
  a.dayID,
  (CASE
    WHEN w.weekLabel is null
    THEN CONCAT('NONE')
    ELSE W.weekLabel
    END) as weekLabel,
  c.uc,
  c.um
FROM
  activity a
  LEFT JOIN phase p ON p.phaseID = a.phaseID
  LEFT JOIN core c ON c.coreID = a.coreID
  LEFT JOIN week w ON w.weekid = a.weekID
WHERE
  c.orgID = :orgID AND
  c.userID = :userID
ORDER BY
  c.coreLabel
  , a.phaseOrderBy
  -- , a.phaseID
  , a.weekOrderBy
  -- , a.weekID
  , a.dayOrderBy
  -- , a.dayID
```

I also have another fiddle which may help illustrate the functionality I'm trying to accomplish: [jsFiddle with sorting implemented](https://jsfiddle.net/SavageCatHV/47v0zr59/14/)

Here is the [dbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kFsYUtGKL4cwkenbHKeF5h/0)

**UPDATE**
Here is an example of what the data *should* look like when the query is ran. This will allow me to loop over the data correctly to generate the output I need. I'm also including a link to the google doc (read only) [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CFubXZUDv-xI0hW087yOJhFNFOcQPs3JoOL30Q149wQ/edit?usp=sharing).

In the picture below, the (1 pink-ish) and (2 yellow-ish) are the known data samples and columns (3),(4), and (5) the desired orderBy ordering.

[image: screen shot of sample data set]

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
Creating that screenshot was an excellent exercise and really made me think about the data (thank you Rick!).

The data in the woaid is simply a PK and I should have randomized it - I just didn't think about it so I apologize for the confusion it may have caused.

Scenario: let's say the user drags the day item corresponding to woaid=19 from coreid=444 to the coreid=232/phaseID=19/weekID=1 and wants this item to be the last item displayed under the new location week (it was the only item under it's old location so it was natually just a '1'). It's dayOrderBy id would be changed from 1 to 4 (it's coreID,phaseID,weekID would also be updated accordingly). The next visit to the page should reflect the correct sort order AND location meaning the day corresponding to woaid=19 should now displayed as the 4th item under coreid=232/phaseID=19/weekID=1/dayID=7 (the dayID doesn't change, only the orderByDayID would change).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: New project, no table yet. I've done a sorting in the past but it was only a single layer so sorting was straight forward. This one I _think_ might not be as striaght forward.

Comment: @RickJames additional fiddles (include a create table fiddle) have been added. The  original question has been revised to remove some fluff from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about `ORDER BY`, I see 2 approaches:

Plan A:  Construct the query (especially the `ORDER BY` part) dynamically, then execute it.  This lets you use whatever column the user needs.

Plan B:  Have a `CASE` or `IF()` expression to compute a single value to order by.  Example:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN ... THEN phaseOrderBy
         WHEN ... THEN weekOrderBy
         ...
    END
```

Or...

```
ORDER BY
    IF(..., phaseOrderBy, IF(..., weekOrderBy, ... ))
```

Based on the image provided, either of these would give the desired ordering:

```
ORDER BY coreID, phaseOrderBy, weekOrderBy
```

or simply

```
ORDER BY woAID
```

Comment: How would I go about performing either option with the given query? Or, are you suggesting running the query multiple times based upon the phase / week / or day of data needed for the output?

Comment: @HPWD - What controls that choice?  Some other column?  Some input parameter?

Comment: What choice are you referring to? In the where clause, the `:userID` and the `:orgID` are just session variables from the user users authentication into the admin area of the web site.

Comment: @HPWD - I am confused.  Please provide an example of the output you desire.

Comment: added screen shot of sample data as well as a read-only link to a google doc to help.

Comment: @HPWD - That picture would use `ORDER BY coreID, phaseOrderBy, weekOrderBy`.  Nothing in that screenshot indicates the importance of `dayOrderBy`, but perhaps it should be on the end.

Comment: @HPWD - But this would also work:  `ORDER BY woAID`.  So I still don't understand the question.

Comment: Creating that screenshot was an excellent exercise and really made me think about the data. The data in the woaid is simply a PK and I should have randomized it - I just didn't think about it. Scenario: let's say the user drags the day item corresponding to woaid=19 from coreid=444 to the  coreid=232/phaseID=19/weekID=1 and wants this item to be the last item displayed under the new location week. It's dayOrderBy id would be changed from 1 to 4 (it's coreID,phaseID,weekID would also be updated accordingly). The next visit 2 page should reflect the correct sort order (the item under new group).

Comment: The answer was two-fold. Your comment of `ORDER BY coreID, phaseOrderBy, weekOrderBy` was the first half. In doing this, I updated my source code (there were several loops that were looping over `coreID` then `phaseID` then `weekID`. Changing those from the *ID to the *OrderBy was the other half of the equation that I didn't realize was part of the problem. Thanks again @rick-james for making me really analyze exactly what I was looking to do, lookng at my data, and forcing me to take a fresh look at my problem.

Comment: if you'll post your comment about the order by as an answer, I'll mark it correct.